# Hibernate vs ActiveJDBC

Tags: hibernate, activejdbc

I am getting frustrated with Hibernate, the need to impleement equals, hascode, attach detach session, etc.. while it promises to ease the pain working in plain JDBC, it is introducing new complexity of its own.

Now ActiveJDBC seems like the holy grail..

[ActiveJDBC: New Java ORM](http://java.sys-con.com/node/1912289)

[ActiveJDBC Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/)

But have anyone used in large real world application? Any feedback?

Answer (score 4):

Best to post this to the ActiveJDBC community: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/activejdbc-group, I can only speak for myself.
We started using ActiveJDBC in 2009. Currently we have it powering 4 websites for a major insurance company (3 environments for each: test, qa, production), massive batch processing architecture clustered with Weblogic JMS (ten nodes), and a handful of internal projects. We do not use Hibernate anymore, except legacy apps.
Our DB is all Oracle (legacy DB) and our schema is pretty complex, with links to other schemas, sequences, triggers, etc. Current schema size is 90 tables. I have seen other people on ActiveJDBC forums use it on schemas of several hundred tables.

Comment: Hi nice to hear the reassurance from the developer itself.. I will try this on a small project of ours and see how it goes..

Comment: I wrote this blog entry: http://igorpolevoy.blogspot.com/2012/04/just-how-thin-can-framework-be.html, it compares Hibernate and ActiveJDBC in terms of being lightweight

Comment: Oh, and one more thing. I joined Groupon last fall, and we have now two internal projects built on top of ActiveJDBC and ActiveWeb

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Norm](https://github.com/dieselpoint/norm). It's lightweight and very straightforward. It's in heavy production use.